# Separate map declaration and initialization

Tags: c++, dictionary, declaration, definition

Value.h

```
#ifndef  VALUE_H
#define VALUE_H
#include <map>
#include <string>
std::map<uint8_t, std::string> status;
#endif
```

Value.cpp

```
#include "Value.h"
std::map<uint8_t, std::string> status = {
    { 0x00, "Status1" },
    { 0x11, "Status2" },
    { 0x10, "Status3" }
};
```

But I kept getting **redefinition; multiple initialization** Error; How should I declare and initialize? I want the map to be global. Is it possible to not wrap the map in a class? I just want this file to be an information of map and values for other files.

Comment: Just mark it as `extern`...

Answer (score 6):

Note `std::map<uint8_t, std::string> status;` is still a [definition](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/definition), even without initializer (i.e. an empty map).

You can use [extern](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/storage_duration#Explanation) to make it a declaration in `Value.h`;

```
extern std::map<uint8_t, std::string> status;
```

> In addition, a variable declaration that uses extern and has no initializer is not a definition.

Comment: Beautiful :) Thanks!